# Web Part Data into Sharepoint LIst

Tags: list, web-part

I have a custom web part which have  lot of fields that will be filed out by user and on submit is there a way that i can populate these values into a SharePoint list .I don't want to use info path as the web part also has lot of C# code in the background

```
 SPWeb app = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList ListName = app.Lists["Communities Directory"];
            SPListItem ListItem = ListName.Items.Add();
            string[] UsersSeperated = pickAdministrators.CommaSeparatedAccounts.Split(',');
            SPFieldUserValueCollection UserCollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
            foreach (string UserSeperated in UsersSeperated)
            {

                app.EnsureUser(UserSeperated);
                SPUser User = app.SiteUsers[UserSeperated];
                SPFieldUserValue UserName = new SPFieldUserValue(app, User.ID, User.LoginName);
                UserCollection.Add(UserName);
            }
            ListItem["Contact Person"] = UserCollection;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can and would need to use the following:

Lists Web Sevice

```
Lists.UpdateListItems Method (Lists)
```

more can be found at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx

or

In the codebehind for the webpart you could do:

```
SPWeb app = SPContext.Current.Web; 
SPList ListName = app.Lists["YourListName"]; 
SPListItem ListItem = ListName.Items.Add(); 
ListItem["field1Name"] = value; 
ListItem["field2Name"] = value; 
ListItem.Update();
```

taken from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569481/add-items-to-existing-sharepoint-lists-by-coding

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi I am trying to update the share point list item with people picker field and  i am using the following code but its always giving me specified user not found error .I pasted my code in the question .CAn you please help me with that

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply been bussy! have you managed to solve the issue? have you debugged the code to see where exactly its breaking on?